# J2ME Palette Empty after Installing Oracle J2ME SDK and WTK

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, java-me, palette

I need to develop a J2ME app.

I've successfully installed Netbeans 7.4 (clean install) and followed the procedures outlined in the J2ME Install guide (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/quickstart.html#install). I downloaded the Oracle J2ME SDK, activated (it was already active) and installed the platform but when I create a J2ME project something strange happens.

I can't see the usual form navigator on my screen. The most alarming thing here is when I create a new JFrame, my palette is empty, except for a few weird components.

I don't know where I went wrong in the install - this has happened to me several times now - but I tried installing the WTK as well - to no avail. I tried adding components to the palette but there were none to add. Can anyone tell me why my NetBeans is behaving this way?

I've uninstalled it, and re-installed it. What am I missing?

Cheers,
Rowan R. J

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the oracle J2ME sdk netbeans plugin for it to work well with netbeans. For the step by step embedding of the netbeans plugin, I think this page will help.
http://www.tutorialmasterng.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-embed-javatm-platform-me-sdk.html